# How to retrieve external files if wget erobots=off is not working?

Tags: wget

I would like to download all pdf files linked on a website using wget on Mac OS (zsh).

I have tried:

`wget -r -p -k --random-wait --limit-rate=50k -A .pdf -erobots=off https://unfccc.int/process-and-meetings/bodies/constituted-bodies/executive-committee-of-the-warsaw-international-mechanism-for-loss-and-damage-wim-excom/task-force-on-displacement/implementation-updates-task-force-on-displacement\#eq-1`

and I have also added the following options to no avail:

- `--span-hosts`
- `--no-check-certificate`
- `--no-cookies`
- `-H`

The error is always the same:

> no-follow attribute found in unfccc.int/process-and-meetings/bodies/constituted-bodies/executive-committee-of-the-warsaw-international-mechanism-for-loss-and-damage-wim-excom/task-force-on-displacement/implementation-updates-task-force-on-displacement. Will not follow any links on this page

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-e robots=off` not `-erobots=off`? Although it doesn't work either way for me. This may help https://bitbucket.org/intgr/pub/wiki/Ignoring_robots_restrictions_with_wget But I myself stumbled on downloading the correct html.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you has permission to crawl the pages, I'm not gonna be responsible for bad thing happend to you or anyone after bypassing the robot no-follow attribute !

The tricks to ignore all restrictions and be a bad crawler bot you just need to include : 
`-e robots=off` on your command.

Yes, you've included it on your commands but you got some typos !
Just like @x00 say it need to be `-e robots=off` instead of `-erobots=off`.

I Don't know why @x00 doesn't answer the question with his answer :/

Note :
For x00, if you want to me to delete my answer because its nearly similar with yours comment , just command under my answer and i will delete it for you anytime !

Comment: From my comment: "Although it doesn't work either way for me". That's one but not the only reason why I didn't write an answer.